# Why decimals are not printing in the response when decimals values are .00 in request

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have request :

```
[
 {
  "PriorityName": "Medium",
  "RangeHigh": 52000.0000,
  "RangeLow": 50000.0000
 }
]
```

I want response like below :

```
[
  {
    "range": "$52000.0000 - 50000.0000"
  }
]
```

I'm trying like above in screenshot decimals are missing.

I tried

```
payload map {
    range: ("\$" ++ $.RangeHigh as String) ++ " - " ++ ($.RangeLow as String)
}
```

I'm expecting a response like this

```
[
  {
    "range": "$52000.0000 - 50000.0000"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is that in JSON a number could be an integer or a decimal. If a numeric value is `1.0` there is no difference to `1`. An implementation is free to use both interchangeably. Also there is not such thing as a format, so if the number has more decimal digits that are zero they will be probably ignored.

To have the expected output you need to format the number when converting to a string. For that you use the `format` property in the conversion. The value of the format is a a string of [format patterns](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dataweave-types-coercion#properties-for-type-coercion). E.g. `as String {format: "#.0000"}`

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map { range: ("\$" ++ $.RangeHigh as String {format: "#.0000"}) ++ " - " ++ ($.RangeLow as String {format: "#.0000"}) }
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "range": "$52000.0000 - 50000.0000"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below I hope this helps.

Dataweave Script

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
[
  {
    range: "\$" ++ (payload[0].RangeHigh as String) ++ ".0000 - " ++ "\$" ++ (payload[0].RangeLow as String) ++ ".0000"
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "range": "$52000.0000 - $50000.0000"
  }
]
```